# Need help building a simple counter in C#

Tags: c#, loops, counter

So, I'm on to new adventures trying on C# and Visual Studio but i can't seem to get anywhere. A friend asked me to help her out in visual studio, and now we're stuck.

I would like to build a counter program which allows the user to input a value up to 30 or 40 or something (it should give an error if the user put in a too high value), and the program will then count until it reaches that value and output all the numbers on the way so that they can be read.
However I'm having trouble understanding how to get get the program to do this since I'm new to both loops and visual studio.

My webform looks like this:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Headline" runat="server" CssClass="h1" Text="Counter"></asp:Label>

    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="h1" runat="server" Text="input a value"></asp:Label>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="txtValue_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" OnClick="btnGo_Click" Text="Go" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

And my C# is still empty since I dont really know how to connect them. All i know is that i should write it under the onclick function somehow.

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: So you want that we write it for you, dude?

Comment: its basically a for loop where `i <= usersInputValue`, what have you tried?

Comment: Seems like you want to do it on web page. Then better do it in JavaScript.

Comment: I've read the tutorials on how to build loops, the problem is mainly getting it to connect to the onClick function. Like this: {
     
 int i = 0;
 while (i < 10)
 {
     lblOutput.Write("While statement ");
     // Write the index to the screen.
     lblOutput.WriteLine(i);
     // Increment the variable.
     i++;
 } But I really dont get how to connect it to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple console application that will give some indication of how you will solve this problem (this can be placed in the onClick event):

```
var userInput = 40; //This will be set to what the user has entered in the text box.

        if (userInput < 1000) //1000 will be set the the max value you will allow.
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= userInput; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            //Give User an Error
        }
```